# Zip file is fine on server side but corrupted after serving to the client side

Tags: java, http, zip, nanohttpd

I'm trying to zip up a bunch of image and csv files into a zip file on the server side and send it to the client in the browser to be downloaded. The zipfile works fine on the client side but the version being served to the client in a response gives an error 21 is a directory when being unzipped. What am I missing out here?

The error I got when I tried opening with archive utility was "Error 21 - Is a directory"

The error I got with The Unarchiver is that the archive file is incomplete.

The error I got with unzip was

```
jcl$ unzip compliment.zip 
Archive:  compliment.zip
??
caution:  zipfile comment truncated
error [compliment.zip]:  missing 3231972691 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [compliment.zip]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

It looks like it might either be corrupted or not transferred in binary so I tried setting the response MIME type to "application/zip" and "application/octet-stream" and receiving it in the same format in a blob on the javascript client. But I still got the same errors.

Server side

```java
public Response serve(String uri, Method _method, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> params, Map<String, String> formFields) {
    Method method = (Method) _method;
    Response response = null;
    try {
        if (Method.PUT.equals(method)) {
            if ("/".equals(uri)) {
                response = index();
            } else {
                File zipFile = getZipByName(params);
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    if (zipFile.exists()) {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
                    } else
                        Log.d("FOF :", "File does not exist:");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                response = newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, "application/zip", fis);
            }
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "serve exception", e);
    }
}
```

Client side

```
function zip(name) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'put',
        url: '/zip/name?' + $.param({name: name}),
        success: function (data) {
            save(name + ".zip", data, 'application/zip');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            reveal('ERROR: <br/><pre>' + jqXHR.responseText + '</pre>', 10000);
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        reveal(name + ".zip generated");
    });
}

function save(filename, data, dataType) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: dataType});
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else{ // Others
        var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        elem.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
```

The expected result is that after downloading the zip file on the client side, it can be unzipped with no errors and the content be the same as the server side copy

Comment: How about comparing the files?

Comment: @JulianReschke I've compared them and they have different shas, so it looks like the file is corrupted while sending to the client. But looking at other questions on stack overflow about sending a zip file over, this seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: Did the length change?

Comment: yea the length was longer than before